# What should a noob know before opening a port to the world?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, sftp

I have done port-forwarding in the past, so that specific applications can be accessed from outside our network, namely security cameras. Yet, something about opening an SFTP or an ssh port to the world, so that anybody can try to access my server seems like walking through a cave without a flashlight. What kind of precautions should I take to secure my PC before I open it to the world?

EDIT 1:

If I don't advertise my IP/port combo to the world, what kind of traffic can I except?

Comment: One thing I always do is move services, such as FTP or SSH to another port. Something random so potential attackers can't make hack attempts on standard ports. It's not a solution but it slows them down. Scan your logs regularly for access attempts too. I get a few hundred attempts per day when I have port 22 (SSH) open. Also consider a mechanism like fail2ban which will ban repeated failed attempts. Mostly you just cross your fingers and hope usernames & passwords are strong.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom What logs do I need to read?

Comment: The actual logs are dependent on the operating system. Most linux logs are stored in /var/log. For example, /var/log/auth or /var/log/secure /var/log/maillog etc. From memory ssh attempts are logged in the /var/log/auth or /var/log/secure/. The grep tool use useful, sudo grep 'fail' /var/log/somelogname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same question like you.
First, it depends on the type of your server.
If you have a hardware server, you can safely drop sshd service or limit its acceptance to internal traffic like 192.168.0.0/16.

But if you have a cloud server like I do. You need to reckon the ssh guessing attack. Check `cat /var/log/secure` you will find uninvited guests who tried to guess the password to get lucky and control your server.

If your application is unique, you just leave the port to the outside. And that would not pose a big problem because most hackers won't know how to break into that application. The most common attack you will encounter is this ssh guessing attack.

3 ways to avoid it, and you can choose them according to your feel:

1) alter the cloud firewall to accept only your app port not ssh port when you do not maintain the server through ssh client. This is a submarine policy.

2) install fail2ban to deny the attacker who is identified by entering the wrong code over 5 times within 10 minutes (these two parameters can be modified though)

3) generate private key - public key pairs and download the private key to log in, then ban password ssh forever.

you will find how-to's on 2 & 3 easily. A few notifications:

2) `yum install epel-release` will broaden the application base for CentOS and help you install fail2ban; in custom configuration jail.local you need to modify the following:

```
bantime = -1s
[sshd]
enabled = yes
```

3) id_rsa is the private key, add ".ppk" to its name so it can be used by Putty.

Comment: I wouldn't say my my application is unique. I just plan on storing unimportant files and seeing what I can learn. Also, I'm not getting any hits on "submarine policy". Are you simply suggesting to change the port?

Any benefits to using CentOS over Ubuntu for this application?

Comment: submarine policy is to make the service available only when you need it, not 24/7. change the port will help a little, because a newbie hacker can scan ports using netcat application to discover whether it is an ssh port.